help me please with inbound email
I created an inbound mail in civimail account, configured as IMAP. When I do the test run the mail works correctly and notifies me that new messages have been found. Now I cannot figure out where I should go to read these new messages considering that in the corresponding contacts it does not add new activity. Thanks for the help

can you use Find Activities to track them down?
